# What are .so scrpits used for and why some of them has hard-coded dependencies?

Tags: linux, gcc, ld

I'm trying to set up a cross-compile software project for a ARM board.

The board has some libraries in its rootfs that are not in the host computer. So to make sure the linker can link to them, I copied the rootfs to a local directory  and use `-Wl,-rpath-link=${Target}` to point the linker to it.

**Problem:**

`ld` can not find glibc.

**Analysis:**

With `-Wl,--verbose` option, `ld` shows:

```
opened script file {Target}/usr/lib/libpthread.so

opened script file {Target}/usr/lib/libc.so
```

**libc.so:**

```
    /* GNU ld script
   Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
   the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-littlearm)
GROUP ( /lib/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a  AS_NEEDED ( /usr/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 ) )
        ^^^^^          ^^^^^^^^^                              ^^^^^^^^^
```

**libpthread.so**

```
/* GNU ld script
   Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
   the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-littlearm)
GROUP ( /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 /usr/lib/libpthread_nonshared.a )
        ^^^^^^^^                 ^^^^^^^^^
```

So when I point `ld` to the libraries I copied from the board's rootfs, it will open those two scripts from there, which has hard coded dependencies.

However, if I don't use `-rpath`, then `ld` would use the scripts that comes with the cross-compiler(`/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libpthread.so` and `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libc.so`), which also have hard coded path in it, but are correct ones.

**Question:**

1. What are those scripts used for?
2. Why some of them has hard coded paths(`libc.so`, `libpthread.so`) but some desn't(`libgcc_s.so`)?

**Update:**

The rootfs I copied from the board is a Yocto distro.

The host computer that I use is Ubuntu14.04 LTS x86-64.

Comment: Google for "linux shared object files" or "linux dynamic library". Those are not "scripts", they are compiled library code.

Comment: @arkascha try one of `cat /usr/lib32/libc.so`, `cat /usr/libx32/libc.so`, `cat /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so`

Comment: As expected they are ELF binaries, provided I use the paths that make sense for my systems. Loops like they are wrapper scripts on your system, never seen that. No idea how that is meant to work, the linker does not execute some target file, he tries to link it. I can only imagine they are meant to resolver scripts and you are meant to link the result they output.

Comment: @arkascha Seems like a distro-specific problem. Added distro info.